# Opencv memory management

Tags: c++, c, opencv, memory-management

I am not so familiar with opencv and i will have a question about memory management.I have a loop in a function that copies data from buffer to opencv mat;

```
 void my_func(){
    while(1){
     Mat m=cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,type);
     memcpy(m,&buffer,size);
     ....
     ....
  }
```

I can define the m at the top of the function but i am wondered about the zeros function.does it allocates memory on heap or stack?,is there a malloc in the function or is it in the local scope?.
So for the other functions of cv what is this situation?is there documentation about the memory manegement of opencv.Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is a malloc. Each `Mat` instance lives in the local scope, and manages its resources. Note that the data is shared, IIRC, so "copying" two `Mats` means both point to the same data block.

Comment: Try `m.release();` to free the memory.

Comment: @francis the destructor would take care of that, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza : i guess so. You are right to underline it.